# Drop Down Menu determines instances of a form - PHP HTML5 CSS

Tags: php, css, html, web-applications

I'm relatively new to web-programming in general so my question may seem a little ridiculous but I've done a good amount of research and can't seem to figure out an answer...

So I have a basic registration form that registers a competitor for a competition.  The idea is that the school's coach would go and register all of their competitors on the same page.  I'd like for there to be a dropdown menu that an ordinal list of numbers and when a number is selected I'd like 'n' instances of the form to show up where 'n' is the number of competitors.

Is this possible? or should I just put 10 or so registration forms on the page and submit what is filled out? Thanks!

Comment: yep, it's possible. go study some javascript :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible. you would simply put the number into a get variable in the links.

```
register.php?number_of_forms=1
register.php?number_of_forms=2
register.php?number_of_forms=3
```

when they click the link, your register.php page would loop that many times, creating that many forms.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $_GET['number_of_forms'], $i++) {
   // print form here

}
```

Comment: if you were really cool, you would just have an "add another competitor" button on the bottom of your registration page that would use javascript to clone the inputs in the form. this way they can add as many as needed to the registration page. you could also use this technique to limit the cloned fields to only what would be different per competitor (so they don't have to enter their own name in once for each competitor they are entering, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Since the coach needs to fill out all the information, isn't it the same effort to key in form by form to register the competitors? If you are new to web programming, this is the easier approach.

Comment: well the question was more about a programming skill I'd like to have in general - yeah it's probably better to just have a number of forms  but from an aesthetic standpoint it'd be nice to be able to have that number show up dynamically.  Thanks though